# How to change modal content when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 2 modals (box1 and box2) in my code box2 is on top of box1. Both of them have buttons. How can I make my modal 1 appears first and then only when you click his button the content changes to box2 (making box1 disappear)? In my original code I have 4 modals actually but i'll addapt to it later. Also if is possible I would like that this content transition was smooth.
OBS: Please open the code snippet in full page so that the modal shows up

```css
    .conteudo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box, .box2 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 400px;
}

.lineButton button {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
```

```html
    <body>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="box">            
            <div class="boxes">
                <div class="modalTxt">
                    <h1>MODAL 1 <br>Accept?</h1>
                    <div class="lineButton">
                        <button type="submit" class="accept1">Accept</button>
                    </div>                           
                </div>         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box2">            
            <div class="boxes">
                <div class="modalTxt">
                    <h1>MODAL 2 <br>Accept?</h1>
                    <div class="lineButton">
                        <button type="submit" class="accept2">Accept</button>
                    </div>                           
                </div>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is not a task for `button type=submit`which is a specialized button to submit a form

Comment: @Tacoshy There is going to be an input for email in my modal 1 and in the modal 2 there is going to be 3 inputs for first name, last name and phone number. Thats why the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `addEventListener` to the button to listen for a `click` event. Then add a class to CSS to hide elements and give all the elements that should be hidden in that class. Last but not least remove the class from the element you want to show and add it to the element you need to hide.

```js
const BUTTON_1 = document.querySelector('.accept1');
const BOX_1 = document.querySelector('.box');
const BOX_2 = document.querySelector('.box2');

BUTTON_1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  BOX_1.classList.add('d-none');
  BOX_2.classList.remove('d-none');
})
```

```css
.conteudo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box,
.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 400px;
}

.lineButton button {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

/* added CSS */
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="modalTxt">
        <h1>MODAL 1 <br>Accept?</h1>
        <div class="lineButton">
          <button type="submit" class="accept1">Accept</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box2 d-none">
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="modalTxt">
        <h1>MODAL 2 <br>Accept?</h1>
        <div class="lineButton">
          <button type="submit" class="accept2">Accept</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```